# How to post Antiforgery token from IdentityServer 3

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver3, antiforgerytoken

I am using IdentityServer 3 for authentication. When user is authenticated then IdentityServer makes a 'POST' request to client's application url. For example http://localhost/home so far so good everything is working fine.

My Client application is developed in ASP.NET Core. In client application i want to validate every POST request. So instead of adding `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on each action method, i have created a middleware that validates every POST request.

```
public class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly IAntiforgery _antiforgery;

    public ValidateAntiForgeryTokenMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        _next = next;
        _antiforgery = antiforgery;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper() == "POST")
        {
            await _antiforgery.ValidateRequestAsync(httpContext);
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }
}
```

The problem here is since identityserver is also making POST, the middleware tries to validate that request but the POST request fails with the following error

> "The required antiforgery cookie
>   \".AspNetCore.Antiforgery.AXelvXewLHI\" is not present."

In Identity Server i have custom login page. and i have configured anti-forgery-token in login page.

```
<div ng-show="model.loginUrl">
    <div class="cr-login-dialog col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form name="form" method="post" action="{{model.loginUrl}}" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <anti-forgery-token token="model.antiForgery"></anti-forgery-token>
            <div class="form-group">
                //user name controls goes here
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                //password controls goes here
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="model.allowRememberMe">
                // remember me controls goes here
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should separate out your anti-xsrf middleware to only run on your requests, not the requests to IdentityServer. IdentityServer does its own anti-xsrf token unrelated to MVC's implementation (as IdentityServer has no dependencies on MVC).

Comment: Well thats the issue. The middleware cannot differentiate if the `POST` request is coming from IdentityServer or user's browser.

Comment: Then using MW as the place to implement that is not the right choice.

Comment: `You should separate out your anti-xsrf middleware to only run on your requests, not the requests to IdentityServer.......`. Note that the middleware will try to validate request `from` identityserver. and i would like identity POST antiforgery token when it redirects to start page of the client application